# Error while running the iPhone app on device

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, ios, code-signing-entitlements

I am getting following error while installing the application on my device. I have given correct application identifier in Entitlement.plist. See the attached snapshot of the error coming in. Any clue?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it appears when you update to a new iOS version without restarting. I'd try to restart XCode or even the Mac.

Answer (score 0):

just delete and recreate the "Entitlements.plist" file

Answer (score 0):

Go in target's property and set name Entitlements.plist before code signing entitlements, just before whr you set provisioning profiles name.
Thanks,